# sqlite database updates only 1 record

Tags: ios, sqlite, ios6, sql-update, xcode4.5

my application uses SQLite database to store certain data of contacts.. like (record_ID, timestamp etc.) I am trying to update SQLITE Records with certain values using this method.

After initializing the database, i used to call this method. Only 1 record is updated,. even if i call this method everytime to update.

```
- (void) updateRecord:(int)recordID:(NSString *)sapCustId:(NSString *)sapContactId: (NSString *)timestamp {


static sqlite3_stmt *updateStmt = nil;

    if(updateStmt == nil) {
        NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"update contactList set sapCustId = \"%@\", sapContactId = \"%@\", timestamp = \"%@\" Where record_ID = \"%d\"", sapCustId, sapContactId, timestamp, recordID];

        const char *sql_stmt = [sql UTF8String];

        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(databaseHandle, sql_stmt, -1, &updateStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
            NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating update statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(databaseHandle));
    }

//        sqlite3_bind_text(updateStmt, 0, [sapCustId UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
//        sqlite3_bind_text(updateStmt, 1, [sapContactId UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
//        sqlite3_bind_int(updateStmt, 2, recordID);
//        sqlite3_bind_text(updateStmt, 3, [timestamp UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

    if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(updateStmt))
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error while updating. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(databaseHandle));

sqlite3_reset(updateStmt);
sqlite3_close(databaseHandle);

//Reclaim all memory here.
[sapContactId release];
[sapCustId release];

}
```

Let me know., how to solve it?

Comment: where are you opening your database?

Comment: opening it where i call the updateRecord method.. i.e. first i call [gss initDatabase]; then [gss updateRecord:record_ID:sapCustId:sapContactId:timestamp];

Comment: Why don't you call `sqlite3_finalize`?

Comment: I'd suggest calling `sqlite3_open` at the same logical level as `sqlite3_close` (if you open from the calling routine, you should close there; if you open in `updateRecord`, you should close here). But that's probably not your issue. Also, rather than `sqlite3_reset` you should call `sqlite3_finalize`. But again, that's unlikely to be the issue.

Comment: calling sqlite3_finalize(updatestmt) causes crash in the 2nd call to updateRecord method, at if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(updateStmt))

Comment: Yikes, I see a significant problem. You're saving your prepared `updateStatement` even though you've closed your database and you're reopening it?!? First, you shouldn't be opening and closing the database for every row. Second, you shouldn't be using a previously prepared statement for a separate opening of a database (esp since that prepared statement only updates the first row).

Comment: Just get rid of that static stuff and make sure you prepare, step, and finalize each `UPDATE` SQL statement. You could do something with your preserved `sqlite3_stmt` if (a) you were binding statements rather than building the SQL from scratch each time; (b) you weren't opening and closing your database all the time.

Comment: thanks everyone i got d answer!.. @Rob was right..

Comment: @Rob i am getting Assertion failure error while updating ..

Comment: @ibiren Very good. I've provided an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14389381/1271826) there. In general, though, it's frustrating when you tell us you're getting an assertion error, but you don't tell us what the assertion was. You go through all of this work to perform `sqlite3_errmsg` to get nice descriptive error messages, and then you don't share them with us. Always tell us (a) what the assertion was, the full thing and any associated `NSLog` statements; and (b) tell us where it was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The critical issue is that you code is building `updateStmt` only once, because that's a `static` and you're checking to see if it's not `nil`. Thus, the first SQL statement is getting built, but none of the rest are. The simplest fix it to just get rid of the `static` qualifier as well as the `if(updateStmt == nil) ...` logic, and you should be off to the races. Also, make sure to replace the `sqlite3_reset` with `sqlite3_finalize`.

The `static` pattern that this code clearly used to do (reusing the `sqlite3_stmt`, binding `?` placeholders in the SQL with new values via `sqlite3_bind_xxx` each iteration, performing `sqlite3_reset` before each subsequent iteration) makes sense if you're using precisely the same SQL statement but are just binding new values each iteration. But it looks like you've commented out that portion of the code and have removed the `?` placeholders from the SQL, and are instead building the SQL using `stringWithFormat`.

The simplest solution is to just retire the `static` pattern (get rid of the `static` keyword, eliminate the check to see if it's `nil`, and use `sqlite3_finalize` in lieu of `sqlite3_reset`) and you should be ok.

---

Additional thoughts:

1. It looks like you're closing the database every time you update a single row. If you're updating a bunch of records, you might want to contemplate keeping the database open. And even if you decide to open and close the database, it probably makes sense to do those at the same logical level in the code (either both inside the `updateRecord` method, or both outside the `updateRecord` method). It just makes for more intuitive code.
2. Assuming you decide that you don't want to bother with reusing a previously prepared SQL statement in order to perform multiple `UPDATE` statements, which would *require* the use of the SQLite `bind` function calls, that does not mean that you shouldn't contemplate using those `bind` function calls anyway. While it might look a lot more convenient to just build the SQL via `stringWithFormat`, it generally is better to use `sqlite3_bind_xxx` calls because (a) that protects you against injection attacks; and (b) you don't have to worry about escaping parameter values that, for example, have quotation marks in them, etc.

   Don't get in the habit of building SQL with `stringWithFormat` because, as a general rule, it's fragile and in some cases, it's dangerous.
3. In your SQL, you generally would not use quotation marks around numeric field values.
4. If you ever decided to try to make the `static sqlite3_stmt`/`sqlite3_reset` logic work, two minor observations:

   - I would not use the same `sqlite3_stmt` across data sessions (i.e. don't close the database and then reopen it). Maybe it works, but given that the database is a parameter to `sqlite3_prepare_v2`, I wouldn't make any such assumptions.
   - When you do, finally, close your database, you really should call `sqlite3_finalize` on the `sqlite3_stmt` and set it back to `nil` again.

Answer (score 0):

You are not opening your database :-

```
- (void) updateRecord:(int)recordID:(NSString *)sapCustId:(NSString *)sapContactId: (NSString *)timestamp {

//OPEN DATABASE HERE
[gss initDatabase]; 
static sqlite3_stmt *updateStmt = nil;

    if(updateStmt == nil) {
        NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"update contactList set sapCustId = \"%@\", sapContactId = \"%@\", timestamp = \"%@\" Where record_ID = \"%d\"", sapCustId, sapContactId, timestamp, recordID];

        const char *sql_stmt = [sql UTF8String];

        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(databaseHandle, sql_stmt, -1, &updateStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
            NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating update statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(databaseHandle));
    }

//        sqlite3_bind_text(updateStmt, 0, [sapCustId UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
//        sqlite3_bind_text(updateStmt, 1, [sapContactId UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
//        sqlite3_bind_int(updateStmt, 2, recordID);
//        sqlite3_bind_text(updateStmt, 3, [timestamp UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

    if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(updateStmt))
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error while updating. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(databaseHandle));

sqlite3_reset(updateStmt);
sqlite3_finalize(updateStmt);
sqlite3_close(databaseHandle);

//Reclaim all memory here.
[sapContactId release];
[sapCustId release];

}
```

Add code of your open database where I have written in comment.

Hope it helps you..

Comment: after calling the initDatabase method in the right place., also its not updating records in Db. (in my -didselectrow method i am calling UPDATERECORD method with manual inputs.) #not getting any error

Comment: @ibiren Copy my editted code and paste it, you missed some lines