# Application crashes with Assertion Failure message while updating SQLite database

Tags: ios, sqlite, sql-update, xcode4.5

In my application i keep some data in local Sqlite db. Sqlite open, insert all working fine. but when i try to update data of a particular row/record if fails with ASSERTION FAILURE message..

*** Assertion failure in -[gss_databaseHandler updateRecord::::], /Users/gss/Desktop/SalesPro copy/SalesPro/../gss_databaseHandler.m:210

```
NSString *databasePath;
// Method to open a database, the database will be created if it doesn't exist
-(void)initDatabase
{
// Create a string containing the full path to the sqlite.db inside the documents folder
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
databasePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"contact1"];

// Check to see if the database file already exists
bool databaseAlreadyExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:databasePath];

// Open the database and store the handle as a data member
if (sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &databaseHandle) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    // Create the database if it doesn't yet exists in the file system
    if (!databaseAlreadyExists)
    {
        // Create the contactList table
        const char *sqlStatement = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS contactList (sapCustId TEXT, sapContactId TEXT, record_ID NUMERIC PRIMARY KEY, timestamp TEXT)";
        char *error;
        if (sqlite3_exec(databaseHandle, sqlStatement, NULL, NULL, &error) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
                NSLog(@"Database and tables created.");
        }
        else
        {
                NSLog(@"Error: in creating/opening database");
        }

    }
  }
}


- (void) updateRecord:(int)recordID:(NSString *)sapCustId:(NSString *)sapContactId:(NSString *)timestamp {

[self initDatabase];

sqlite3_stmt *updateStmt = nil;

    if(updateStmt == nil) {
        const char *sql_stmt = "update contactList Set sapCustId = ?, sapContactId = ?, timestamp = ? Where record_ID = ?";

     if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(databaseHandle, sql_stmt, -1, &updateStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
         NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating update statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(databaseHandle));
    }

    sqlite3_bind_text(updateStmt, 0, [sapCustId UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(updateStmt, 1, [sapContactId UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_int(updateStmt, 2, recordID);
    sqlite3_bind_text(updateStmt, 3, [timestamp UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

    if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(updateStmt))
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error while updating. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(databaseHandle));

sqlite3_finalize(updateStmt);
sqlite3_close(databaseHandle);

//Reclaim all memory here.
[sapContactId release];
[sapCustId release];

}
```

Pls help!..

Comment: @Lefteris Updated it with ERROR message!

Comment: From your sql update statement, I see that your recordID should be the 4th and not the 3rd variable passed into tte sqlite_bind

Comment: @Lefteris i changed it accordingly.. and yet receiving the same error.

Comment: @ibiren You've gone through all of the effort to log the `sqlite3_errmsg`, which is the critical part of the error, but you don't share that with us. That's the part we need. The fact that the assertion took place isn't as interesting as the `sqlite3_errmsg`, which will tell us why. It's buried in the console log, so you'll just have to take a look at it. In terms of your error, lefteris is correct about the order of the parameters, and Prateek is incorrect regarding `sqlite3_reset` (though he is correct regarding it being a 1-based index).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

You are missing sqlite3_reset, and numbering should start from 1

```
- (void) updateRecord:(int)recordID:(NSString *)sapCustId:(NSString *)sapContactId:(NSString *)timestamp {

[self initDatabase];

sqlite3_stmt *updateStmt = nil;

    if(updateStmt == nil) {
        const char *sql_stmt = "update contactList Set sapCustId = ?, sapContactId = ?, timestamp = ? Where record_ID = ?";

     if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(databaseHandle, sql_stmt, -1, &updateStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
         NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating update statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(databaseHandle));
    }

    sqlite3_bind_text(updateStmt, 1, [sapCustId UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(updateStmt, 2, [sapContactId UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(updateStmt, 3, [timestamp UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_int(updateStmt, 4, recordID);

    if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(updateStmt))
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error while updating. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(databaseHandle));

sqlite3_reset(updateStmt);
sqlite3_finalize(updateStmt);
sqlite3_close(databaseHandle);

//Reclaim all memory here.
[sapContactId release];
[sapCustId release];

}
```

Hope this helps you..

EDIT :-

You have not added `sqlite3_finalize();` in any of your previous function and so you are getting database lock error..

Comment: neither getting crashed nor getting updated!.. also sqlite3_reset(updatestmt) should be used when sqlite3_stmt is STATIC?..

Comment: But what are you getting after Error while updating. in NSLog

Comment: Error while updating. 'database is locked'

Comment: YES, now finally we got main issue you are facing, check in every function have you written sqlite3_finalize();, you are missing somewhere, due to which your database is getting locked..

Comment: @Prateek This answer is **incorrect** regarding `sqlite3_finalize` and `sqlite3_reset`. ibiren _should_ call `sqlite3_finalize` and does not need call `sqlite3_reset`. The [latter](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/reset.html) is for reseting a prepared statement so you can execute it again, which ibires is not doing here. The problem in the original code was the order of the bind statements and not starting the index at one, and has nothing to do with `sqlite3_reset`.

Comment: @ibiren you say "also sqlite3_reset(updatestmt) should be used when sqlite3_stmt is STATIC?" Yes, but then again, you wouldn't use the static given that `updateRecord` is opening and closing the database each time. So, in short, `sqlite3_reset` is not appropriate here.

Comment: @Rob No, the issue was not sqlite3_reset. The issue was that sqlite3_finalize() was not written in previous functions, so database was locked and why down vote?

Comment: @Rob Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658565/database-is-locked-in-sqlite. Its all because of database getting locked.

Comment: @Rob Your reputation is so good and still if you reply in such way, that's not good :(

Comment: @Prateek Your answer leads with "You are missing sqlite3_reset and ..." That's incorrect and leads people to draw the wrong conclusions about `sqlite3_reset`. That's why I voted it down. If you edit the answer, I'm happy to remove my downvote.

Comment: @Rob Whats wrong in writing sqlite3_reset, its always good to write that, its free ups memory and make statement back to initial state..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22930/discussion-between-rob-and-prateek)

Answer (score 1):

So, a couple of thoughts:

1. As Prateek and Lefteris suggested, you should change the order of the `bind` calls so that they match the order of the fields in the SQL. They also start with an index of one, not zero. I've always found it odd that the index for `sqlite3_bind` calls start at one, whereas the index for `sqlite3_column` calls start at zero, but it's just the way it works.
2. While it's probably fine, if you ever do an assertion, you should generally make sure you first (a) finalize any successfully prepared statements; and (b) close the database. You don't want to risk leaving your database in an inconsistent state.
3. You probably should not release `sapContactId` or `sapCustId` here. You didn't `retain` or do anything to increase their retain count, so it's probably not prudent to be releasing them here. If you run your code through the static analyzer (press <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> or choose "Analyze" from the product menu), you'll undoubtedly see suggestions/warnings there.
4. As outlined in the official SQLite [An Introduction To the SQLite C/C++ Interface](http://www.sqlite.org/cintro.html), your sequence of `open`, `prepare_v2`, `step`, `finalize`, and `close` is perfectly correct. You do not need to call `sqlite3_reset`. The [purpose](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/reset.html) of `reset` is to allow you to reuse a previous prepared `sqlite3_stmt`, but you're not doing that here, so `reset` is unnecessary here and achieves nothing.
5. At one point in your comments, you said that you received an error "database locked". If you're still getting that having addressed the above items, let us know where you're getting it (at `open`? during the `prepare` of a SQL statement?), as there can be different sources of this problem. Certainly multi-threaded database operations can cause this. You need help us diagnose this by showing us precisely which line you're getting this locked message on, and describe what other database operations (beyond the code in your original question) that you might be doing, especially if you're doing anything in a background queue/thread.

   The challenge in solving "database locked" problems is that the problem invariably is not in the code in which you're experiencing the "database locked" error, but in some previous database interaction that you failed to handle properly. Technically, a failure to call `sqlite3_finalize` could cause the "database locked" problem, but in practice that's rarely the case. I see "database locked" errors usually occurring because of other issues, but we really need to know whether you're experiencing it during the opening of the database, or while trying to `prepare` or `step` a SQL statement. You need to tell us which for us to go further in the diagnosis. But, like I said, the problem undoubtedly rests in other/prior database interactions, so you might need to share more about what other database operations you're doing *prior* to the "database locked" error.

---

If you're interested in a discussion regarding the rewrite of the code in your original question, see below.

A minor suggestion, but I'd suggest altering your `initDatabase` method to make sure you log an error message if the `sqlite3_open` call fails, such as:

```
-(void)initDatabase
{
    // Create a string containing the full path to the sqlite.db inside the documents folder
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *databasePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"contact1.sqlite"];
    
    // Check to see if the database file already exists
    bool databaseAlreadyExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:databasePath];
    
    // Open the database and store the handle as a data member
    if (sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &databaseHandle) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        // Create the database if it doesn't yet exists in the file system
        if (!databaseAlreadyExists)
        {
            // Create the contactList table
            const char *sqlStatement = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS contactList (sapCustId TEXT, sapContactId TEXT, record_ID NUMERIC PRIMARY KEY, timestamp TEXT)";
            char *error;
            if (sqlite3_exec(databaseHandle, sqlStatement, NULL, NULL, &error) == SQLITE_OK)
            {
                NSLog(@"Database and tables created.");
            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"%s: error creating table: %s", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(databaseHandle));
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"%s: error opening database: %s", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(databaseHandle));
    }
}
```

Second, you look at `insertRecord`:

- You want to fix the order that you use the four bind statements.
- You can also eliminate the redundant `if` statement.
- If you use assertions or return from the middle of a method doing database interactions, you always want to do a graceful cleanup. For example, you'll see if my prepare failed, I'll just close, but if the `step` failed, then I make sure to `finalize` and `close`.
- You probably should get rid of those inappropriate `release` statements, moving them to the right place in the code.
- You should change the method signature to have named parameters (because in the [General Rules](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingMethods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001282-1001751-BCIJHEDH) section of the *Coding Guidelines,* Apple says that we should name our method keywords.

Thus:

```
- (void) insertRecord:(int)recordID
            sapCustId:(NSString *)sapCustId
         sapContactId:(NSString *)sapContactId
            timestamp:(NSString *)timestamp
{
    [self initDatabase];
    
    sqlite3_stmt *statement = nil;
    
    const char *sql_stmt = "INSERT INTO contactList (sapCustId, sapContactId, timestamp, record_ID) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
    
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(databaseHandle, sql_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSLog(@"%s: insert prepare error: '%s'", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(databaseHandle));
        sqlite3_close(databaseHandle);
        NSAssert(0, @"insert prepare error");
    }
    
    sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [sapCustId UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 2, [sapContactId UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 3, [timestamp UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_int(statement, 4, recordID);
    
    if (sqlite3_step(statement) != SQLITE_DONE)
    {
        NSLog(@"%s: insert step error: '%s'", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(databaseHandle));
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        sqlite3_close(databaseHandle);
        NSAssert(0, @"insert step error");
    }
    
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    sqlite3_close(databaseHandle);
}
```

Comment: thanks for all ur suggestions.. i would definitely take care of it.